# How to write a code for sleep command in ssh. I tried the code in my putty Sleep 5 and sleep command but it sis not working

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

sleep 5
sleep 20

This code is not working for me in my putty

Comment: Do you want to sleep 5 and than 20 seconds? Use `sleep 5; sleep 20`.

Comment: no actually am trying to deploy this in a program when i run the program it must sleep for a particular time and then it should retain osh shell to type the other commands

Answer (score 0):

Your line `sleep 5 sleep 20` is seen as te command sleep with the parameters `5 sleep 20`. Just use `sleep 5`.